# Are repeating background + transparent linear gradient combined not compatible with floats?

Tags: css, css-float, linear-gradients

This needs to be compatible with all modern browsers and IE7 and IE8.

What I'm trying to do is have a repeated background image for the page with a linear fade that makes the bottom darker. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KqvC.jpg

Here's my example code: http://jsfiddle.net/hxk2d/2/

As you can see, I have two floated divs in the example above. The body linear gradients do not show up for some reason. I figured out it was because of the left div being floated.

As soon as I delete the float for the left div, you start to see a gradient but it only appears within the container.

Obviously, I'd prefer this to work whether there's a floated div or not. My test browsers were both Chrome and Firefox, both of which performed the same behavior.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Please look at my example, I'm not 100% sure but I think the parent div of your two floats didn't had a height calculating as a result of the 2 floating div's, the parent tag of that div is the body that doesn't have any height because nothing inside has, as a quick fix i added some the clearfix class to the parent of the floating div's

Here is the example link:
http://jsfiddle.net/sHXf2/

I modified your gradients to make them more visible, Hope this helped

Comment: Cool, thanks! There's two ideas from this problem I displayed: 1. html and body can do either repeating bg or linear gradient, but for some reason the two can't be combined easily and 2. why is a floating div causing a problem with rendering the linear gradient. The clearfix hack might be a decent temporary solution for now. Hadn't thought about it.

Comment: I think the gradient needs to know the height of the element so it can add its color stops, the height of the body depends on its content, you either keep the clearfix or add some inline content see this example where i added text to underneath the floated divs http://jsfiddle.net/mrpollo/SrURv/ I added the clear both to make it stay on the bottom